# ANTD DatePicker Locale

Tags: antd

I have been working with ANTD since version 2.10. DatePicker had no problems with localization.
When I switched to version 2.12.8 DataPicker began to display the months and days of the week in English,
although the prompts in the TextBox are displayed correctly in any selected language. It seems that DatePicker does not interact correctly with the moment.js. How can I fix this? The application is built on the basis of Create-React-App.

```
...
import { LocaleProvider } from 'antd';
import ruRU from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/ru_RU';
...

<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <LocaleProvider locale={ruRU}>
            <App/>
        </LocaleProvider>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out how to solve this?

Comment: Eventually I've moved: createpicker, DatePicker, RangePicker & wrapPicker to the project

Answer (score 6):

This one line worked for me:

```
import 'moment/locale/ru';
```

See 'note' in Antd docs: [antd range picker docs](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Localization)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ru_RU from "antd/lib/locale/ru_RU";

import store from "./store";

moment.locale("ru");

ReactDOM.render(
  <ConfigProvider locale={ru_RU}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
  </ConfigProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`moment.locale("ru");` adding this line fix your problem and ConfigProvider  is localize all antd components

Comment: Be more descriptive about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need import the **dayjs** and **antd** locale. This code worked for me:

```
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd'
import es from 'antd/locale/es_ES'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/es'
dayjs.locale('es')

export default function IndexLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider locale={es}>
      {children}
    </ConfigProvider>
  )
}
```

Antd's documentation: https://ant.design/components/config-provider#components-config-provider-demo-locale